# How to redirect to from autocomplete (jquery)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-autocomplete

My **products.js.coffee**

```
$ ->
  $('#titles').autocomplete(
    source: gon.titles
    minLength: 2).click ->
    $(this).autocomplete 'search'
    return
  return
```

My **index.html.erb**

```
...
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="titles" />
</div>
...
```

In source I have titles from all products (I used gon gem). I would like to choose the product from autocomplete and redirect to the selected product.

*Thanks for your advice!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution **products.js.coffee**

```
doSearch = (term, location) ->
  window.location.href = 'products?utf8=✓&search=' + term + '&commit=Search'
  return

$(document).ready ->
  $('#titles').autocomplete
    minLength: 1
    source: gon.titles
    select: (event, ui) ->
      doSearch ui.item.label, ui.item.city
      return
  return
```